# The connection has timed out error after installing apache2 in Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: server, 22.04, apache2, connection, amazon-ec2

I have installed apache2 in Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. When I hit my IP address in the browser to check the Apache page, I get the below error.

> The connection has timed out

I have tried the below command

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install apache2

sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

I am missing anything here? because I can see that `/var/www/html/index.html` file exist in the folder

Comment: Where is the server? Is it on a local network or on a hosting service such as AWS or Azure? There may be a firewall sitting between the server and the open web which needs to be edited to allow traffic on ports 80 and 443.

Comment: @matigo, it is on AWS. I have only one inbound rules SSH TCP 22 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: I have added 80 and 443 in the inbound rules and it's started working